# read timeseries from sqlite with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sqlite3 database table that I'd like to analyze in pandas.  The database represents a time-series, so I'd my DataFrame to reflect that.  Specifically, I'd like to be able use dates as an index in my DataFrame so that I can do nifty things like [resampling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

Right now, I'm reading the DataFrame as:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
query = """
  SELECT
   *
  FROM DataTable
"""
data = pd.read_sql_query(query, db, parse_dates={'datetime': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'})
```

This dataframe is indexed using sequential integers, not by timestamps as I'd like.  Is there some magic incantation to create a date index on the parsed `datetime` field rather than using sequential integers?

Comment: Can you just do a `data.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)`?

Comment: @JCVanHamme -- Probably.  I'm still figuring out how to wrap my head around pandas.  This is all a new experiment for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this can be accomplished pretty easily by using the `index_col` keyword:

```
data = pd.read_sql_query(
    query,
    db,
    parse_dates={'datetime': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'},
    index_col='datetime')
```